# Solving 50Mb per app issue by having both multiple apks and an expansion file

Tags: android, google-play, apk-expansion-files, multiple-apk

I'm going to publish my app into google developer's console, but discovered that there is an app limit of 50MB, and to solve the issue I have 2 options:
1) expansion files
and 
2) multiple apks

So I tried to use the second option and distributed the images among several apks according to screen sizes. The size of single apk has, of course, decreased, but still exceeds 50MB. Is it possible to have an expansion file and multiple apks?

Comment: Limit is now 100MB: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html

Answer (score 0):

I think , you have problem to understand about multiple apks. Google play understand the multiple apks as a one apk but show to user according to user device support screen size .

```
If you apk extend 50mb then you must need to added expansion files.

Here you break the apk to multiple apks for size but still it greater then 50mb then you need to  expansion files.
```

Thanks